# Printing a path in Rust

Tags: rust

How could I print a path in Rust?

I tried the following in order to print the current working directory:

```
use std::os;

fn main() {
    let p = os::getcwd();
    println!("{}", p);
}
```

But `rustc` returns with the following error:

```
[wei2912@localhost rust-basics]$ rustc ls.rs 
ls.rs:5:17: 5:18 error: failed to find an implementation of trait core::fmt::Show for std::path::posix::Path
ls.rs:5     println!("{}", p);
                           ^
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:23: 2:77 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:2 note: in expansion of println!
ls.rs:5:2: 5:20 note: expansion site
```

Comment: aka `PathBuf doesn't implement std::fmt::Display`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As you discovered, the "correct" way to print a `Path` is via the [`.display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.display) method, which returns [a type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Display.html) that implements [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html).

There is a reason `Path` does not implement `Display` itself: formatting a path to a string is a lossy operation. Not all operating systems store paths compatible with UTF-8 and the formatting routines are implicitly all dealing with UTF-8 data only.

As an example, on my Linux system a single byte with value 255 is a perfectly valid filename, but this is not a valid byte in UTF-8. If you try to print that `Path` to a string, you have to handle the invalid data somehow: `.display` will replace invalid UTF-8 byte sequences with the replacement character U+FFFD, but this operation cannot be reversed.

In summary, `Path`s should rarely be handled as if they were strings, and so they don't implement `Display` to encourage that.

Answer (score 16):

The following will print out the full path:

```
println!("{}", p.display());
```

Refer to [`Path::display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.display) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As a related tangent, I've written a library for when you "just want it in UTF-8" [stfu8](https://docs.rs/stfu8/0.2.4/stfu8/).

This uses escape characters (i.e. `\x00`) to format any nearly-UTF-8 sequence the way a developer might expect.